# Props passed to a custom header component come as undefined

Tags: react-native

So, I have a Dashboard component which has a custom header. In the Dashboard component I do an API call and set params, which I pass to the header component. I want to pass userName and pgAddress as props to the header component.

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await client.post('sjsjdldlksd');
      console.log(data.HostelName, data.TenantName);

      this.props.navigation.setParams({
        userName: data.TenantName,
        pgAddress: data.HostelName,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };


Dashboard.navigationOptions = {
  header: (props) => (
    <Header
      navigation={props.navigation}
      userName={props.navigation.getParam('userName')}//using getParams because state.params doesn't work
      pgAddress={props.navigation.getParam('pgAddress')}
      value={2}
    />
  ),
};
```

And I am accessing these two using **props.userName and props.pgAddress**. They both come undefined. 
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those params don't yet exist, so at first they are `undefined`. Use `getParam`'s second parameter to provide a fallback while waiting for the actual params to load in after `componentDidMount`.

For example:

```js
props.navigation.getParam('userName', '')
```

Try getting the `navigation` prop from passing a function to `navigationOptions` instead of to `header`:

```js
Dashboard.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  header: (
    <Header
      navigation={navigation}
      userName={navigation.getParam('username', 'fallbackUsername')
      pgAddress={navigation.getParam('pgAddress, 'fallbackPgAddress')
      value={2}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, the props never load. They always come undefined, the fallback shows almost immediately but the props never show. What do I do in this case?

Comment: Try getting the navigation prop as a parameter from a function sent to `navigationOptions`; I've updated my answer to show how to do that